# Web API.Net Response Types and Serialization

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.6.1

For the following:

```cs
    public class ClientReturnWrapper<T> : ClientReturnWrapperBase
    {
        public ClientReturnWrapper(T returnData) => ReturnData = returnData;
        public T ReturnData { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClientReturnWrapperBase
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp => DateTime.Now;
        public bool HasErrors => ClientReturnErrors != null;
        public IList<ClientReturnError> ClientReturnErrors { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClientReturnError
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public bool ErrorIsFatal { get; set; }
    }
```

This:

```cs
    public ClientReturnWrapper<int> Test()
    {
        return new ClientReturnWrapper<int>(1);
    }
```

Returns:

```
    {"ReturnData":1,"Timestamp":"2019-10-02T12:38:50.9493925+01:00","HasErrors":false,"ClientReturnErrors":null}
```

Whereas:

```cs
    public ClientReturnWrapperBase TestError()
    {
        return new ClientReturnWrapperBase();
    }
```

Returns:

```xml
    <ClientReturnWrapperBase xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Shiva.Models">
        <ClientReturnErrors i:nil="true"/>
    </ClientReturnWrapperBase>
```

These are both called from a browser, and I would expect `XML` for both, however the former returns `JSON` whereas the latter correctly returns `XML` albeit with missing properties.

What causes this?

EDIT: To address points below, `JSON` is returned even when specifically requesting `XML`, so I suspect that Generics cannot be serialized by the XML serializer. Is there a workaround for this? Secondly, why are properties missing when the XML serializer is used in the second example?

Answer (score 0):

WebAPI will automatically send JSON or XML based on the Accept header that your client sends, If you want to get XML, just in the client request header add

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe, I understand that - I'm asking why they are serialised differently. Even when explicitly requesting XML the former returns JSON